# What is the difference between attribute Group and Population in Exact Target?

Tags: contactbuilder, attribute, attribute-group

I have 2 tables /Data Extensions and I want to link them in contact builder.
Now I fail to understand if I should link them in Attribute Group or in Population Builder.

Also, when I go to Population, on top right it gives me a + sign to add new Attribute Group.

Can some one help me here about what is the logical difference between Attribute Group and Population and when to use which one?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Thanks,
Richa